# Can't send email where address is hosted on server

Tags: email, postfix, routing

First let me describe my setup.  I have a virtualised server with one VM for ispCP where I host a bunch of websites.  Email for these websites is hosted through Google Apps.

The problem I have is that if I try to send an email from this server (such as from a PHP contact form) to one of the Google Apps email accounts it never arrives but it does arrive if I send it to an email address that does not have a website on the server (e.g. a GMX account).

Looking around, this problem seems to be caused by emails being routed internally. I have looked around but I can't seem to find any simple, clear solution.

I am running on Debian 6 64bit with ispCP and postfix.internal routing postfix

Answer (score 1):

I have not used ispCP myself, but the general solution in this case is to disable local mail hosting for the domain.

According to [this](http://unifix.org/cgi-bin/index.pl?action=show&ID=575) link, this can be done in the GUI:

> - switch to the user (dom.tld)
> - delete all mail accounts
> - switch back to the corresponding reseller
> - change the domain, set the numer of mail accounts to -1 (disable)
> - change the traffic limit 
>     -> ok
> - if needed: change the domain, set the traffic limit back to the previus number
>
> this way the domain is removed from the domain hashfile (the mportant
>   thing is the change of the transfer volume).
>
> Note by BT: The traffic limit trick is needed to invoke the ISPCP
>   Engine, which updates the domains.

Comment: I don't think that this could be the problem as the domain already has email disabled in ispCP.

Comment: then why do you write "caused by emails being routed internally"? If the mail hosting is really disabled messages would be sent to the mx record and *not* be routed internally. A mail log snippet of such a message would probably provide clarity of what happens.